# Wrong output after using OpenMP in C code

Tags: c, openmp

Consider this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef _OPENMP
#include <omp.h>
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, ng, igx1 = 6, dgx = 1, igx2 = 599;
    int *ix_recv;

    ng = (igx2 - igx1) / dgx + 1;
    ix_recv = (int *) malloc(ng); 
    memset(ix_recv, 0, ng * sizeof(int));

    ix_recv[0] = igx1 - 1;

#ifdef _OPENMP
    #pragma omp parallel for default(none) private(i) shared(ix_recv,dgx,ng)
#endif        
    for (i = 0; i < ng - 1; i++) { 
        ix_recv[i + 1] = ix_recv[i] + dgx;
    }
}
```

Without use of OpenMP, `ix_recv` ends up with values `5,6,7,8,...,597,598`, which is what I expect. When OpenMP is used, howver, the results become totally wrong.

What's the problem?

Comment: Please explain why you explicitly make the for loop counter variable `i` private. And describe what happens if you don't, especially what happens which you do not want.

Comment: Note: `malloc` + `memset` to zero is wasteful.  Use `calloc` if you want to allocate memory all initially set to zero.  Also, do not cast the return value of `malloc()` (or `calloc()`).

Comment: What is the output with OpenMP?

Comment: Anyway, why in the world are you trying to parallelize this loop?  Every iteration depends (or should) on the result of the previous one; as written, it is inescapably serial.

Comment: @JohnBollinger what do you mean by "do not cast the return value of malloc()", I'm a little bit confused...

Comment: @Tom, C does not require the cast in your `ix_recv = (int *) malloc(ng)`, and I am among the many who consider it poor form and recommend against it.  Including it can hide flaws in your program, such as omitting the header in which `malloc` is declared.  Just leave it out: `ix_recv = malloc(ng)`.  (In C.  C++ has different rules.)

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks a lot. You said the for loop is serial because every iteration depends on the result of previous one. So could you explain what kind of loop can be parallized?

Comment: The fewer the dependencies between iterations, the better for parallelization a loop is.  Ideally, there would be no dependencies at all.  Your loop could be restructured like that by making each new value of `ix_recv` depend on `ng`, `dgx`, and `igx1`, but not on other elements of `ix_recv`.  There are other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, each iteration carries a dependency on the previous one:

> ```
> for (i = 0; i < ng - 1; i++) { 
>     ix_recv[i + 1] = ix_recv[i] + dgx;
> }
> ```

Note how the value assigned to `ix_recv[i + 1]` depends on the value of `ix_recv[i]`.  The desired value is assigned to the former only if the expected value is read from the latter, which, in a serial execution, happens in the previous iteration.  And that iteration depends on the one before it, and so on, except that you have correctly arranged for the `i == 0` iteration to depend instead on a prior initialization outside the scope of the loop.

Now suppose you break up the loop iterations into chunks that you can assign to separate threads, running in parallel.  Only one thread can get the chunk starting at `i == 0`.  Other threads' first chunks start elsewhere, and if they indeed are executed concurrently then those other threads start off with the wrong value in the preceding member of `ix_recv`.  It is then a case of garbage in / garbage out.

This particular dependency is pretty easy to spot, but general dependency analysis is a hard problem, and OpenMP leaves it to the programmer to handle.  You might find this discussion of the topic illuminating: http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/openmp.html#Dependencyanalysis.  If you do not remove or satisfy all your dependencies, then your parallel program is likely to produce incorrect results.

In your particular case, there are multiple ways to solve the dependency problem.  Here's one:

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
    #pragma omp parallel for
#endif        
    for (int i = 0; i < ng; i++) { 
        ix_recv[i] = igx1 - 1 + dgx * i;
    }
```

Note that the value of each element of `ix_recv` depends only on `i` and on loop invariants.